# Escape Sequence Issue with File Path: \ is stored as \\

Tags: c#, registry

I am trying to load the path of a file from `registry` but I am facing a problem, when I use `\` in string, it is saved as `\\` and when I use `\\` (to make it \ in path string) it is also saved as `\\`. Here's what I am trying to do:

[image: This is what I got when I went to debugging mode]

Because of that `\\` I always get null in `key` variable. How can I resolve this issue?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The double-slash occurs only in the debug-view, the actual valuze however does have only one slash.

Comment: No, it's not actually `\\\`, it's just showing that way in the debugger.  My guess is it's a 64 vs. 32 bit thing.  Maybe you need to debug in 64 bit mode.  The registry under hklm\software targets different keys based on the bitness of the app that's querying it.

Comment: then why I am getting null in the key variable as there is no other reason for getting null except the path is not reachable

Comment: you are pathing in twice to HKLM by calling `OpenSubKey`.

Comment: @ItbanSaeed i edited your question to be more clear. this is not a file path.

Comment: Tell me the solution please.

Comment: drop `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` from the `regPath` string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi The problem is not the escape chars which windows will apply to all uri's

The problem is with the opensubkey method, here you are submitting a key/value so the code you have is looking for a subkey of RibbonUi.xml which does not exist.

Instead seperate the key/value lookup and all will work out fine.

```
            RegistryKey rkApp =
            Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);

            if (rkApp.GetValue("MyTestRun_Key_Value") == null)
            {
                checkbox1.Checked = false;
            }

            else
            {
                checkbox1.Checked = true;
            }
```